# Add polyline to array of markers in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I'm very new to Leaflet and coding, and I'm basically just trying out to see if I can build a random map with different features. I've come across an issue, which I need help with.

I can't add a polyline to an array (see my attempt below), and secondly, I can't make the map fitBounds.

```
// Map settings
var map = L.map('map').setView([11.206051, 122.447886], 8);
mapLink =
  '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
L.tileLayer(
  'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors',
    maxZoom: 18,
  }).addTo(map);
  
// Icons -> https://github.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers
var myIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-gold.png'
});

// Icons2
var myIcon2 = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-violet.png'
});

// Locations
var locations = [
  ["LOCATION_1", 11.8166, 122.0942],
  ["LOCATION_2", 11.9804, 121.9189],
  ["LOCATION_3", 10.7202, 122.5621],
  ["LOCATION_4", 11.3889, 122.6277],
  ["LOCATION_5", 10.5929, 122.6325]
];

// Locations 2
var locations2 = [
  ["LOCATION_1", 9.8166, 122.0942],
  ["LOCATION_2", 9.9804, 121.9189]
];

// Add markers
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new L.marker([locations[i][1], locations[i][2]], {icon: myIcon})
    .bindPopup(locations[i][0])
    .addTo(map);
}

// Add markers2
for (var i = 0; i < locations2.length; i++) {
  marker = new L.marker([locations2[i][1], locations2[i][2]], {icon: myIcon2})
    .bindPopup(locations[i][0])
    .addTo(map);
}

// Add polyline (NOT WORKING)
var polyline = L.polyline([locations[i][1], locations[i][2]], {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);

// Zoom the map to the polyline (NOT WORKING)
map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());
```

Here's a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Enounce/kcwngxe0/17/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`polyline` is outside of the loop so `i` will only take the last value of `locations2.length` which is 2

Better use `let` inside for loops so you won't end up with local for loop variables being exposed outside the for loop block

Moreover if I understood correctly you want to add a polyline between the markers of each locations array, `locations` and `locations2`

So you need to have a data format of array of `latlngs` like so:

```
var locations2 = [
  [9.8166, 122.0942],
  [9.9804, 121.9189]
];
```

to be able to create polylines

You can get that by mapping over the two arrays and returning an array with only lat and longitude.

```
var polyline = L.polyline(locations.map(location => [location[1], location[2]]), {
  color: 'red'
}).addTo(map);
```

You can do the same for locations2 array

```
var polyline2 = L.polyline(locations2.map(location2 => [location2[1], location2[2]]), {
      color: 'red'
    }).addTo(map);
```

Finally to fit the bounds using both polylines you can simply place the two polyline instances in a featureGroup and get its bounds using getBounds method.

```
const featureGroup = L.featureGroup();

featureGroup.addTo(map);

featureGroup.addLayer(polyline);
featureGroup.addLayer(polyline2);

map.fitBounds(featureGroup.getBounds());
```

```js
// Map settings
var map = L.map('map').setView([11.206051, 122.447886], 8);
mapLink =
  '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
L.tileLayer(
  'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors',
    maxZoom: 18,
  }).addTo(map);

// Icons -> https://github.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers
var myIcon = L.icon({
  iconSize: [25, 41],
  iconAnchor: [10, 41],
  popupAnchor: [2, -40],
  iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-gold.png'
});

// Icons2
var myIcon2 = L.icon({
  iconSize: [25, 41],
  iconAnchor: [10, 41],
  popupAnchor: [2, -40],
  iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-violet.png'
});

// Locations
var locations = [
  ["LOCATION_1", 11.8166, 122.0942],
  ["LOCATION_2", 11.9804, 121.9189],
  ["LOCATION_3", 10.7202, 122.5621],
  ["LOCATION_4", 11.3889, 122.6277],
  ["LOCATION_5", 10.5929, 122.6325]
];

// Locations 2
var locations2 = [
  ["LOCATION_1", 9.8166, 122.0942],
  ["LOCATION_2", 9.9804, 121.9189]
];

// Add markers
for (let i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new L.marker([locations[i][1], locations[i][2]], {
      icon: myIcon
    })
    .bindPopup(locations[i][0])
    .addTo(map);

}

var polyline = L.polyline(locations.map(location => [location[1], location[2]]), {
  color: 'red'
}).addTo(map);

console.log(locations.map(location => [location[1], location[2]]))

// Add markers2
for (let i = 0; i < locations2.length; i++) {
  marker = new L.marker([locations2[i][1], locations2[i][2]], {
      icon: myIcon2
    })
    .bindPopup(locations[i][0])
    .addTo(map);
}

var polyline2 = L.polyline(locations2.map(location2 => [location2[1], location2[2]]), {
  color: 'red'
}).addTo(map);

const featureGroup = L.featureGroup();

featureGroup.addTo(map)

featureGroup.addLayer(polyline)
featureGroup.addLayer(polyline2)



map.fitBounds(featureGroup.getBounds());
```

```css
#map {
  height: 700px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id='map'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, kboul. It looks like the polylines and markers aren't aligned properly. Do you know what the issue could be?

Comment: Yes, you need to use proper `iconSize` and `iconAnchor`. I updated the demo.

Comment: You were absolutely right. I need to remind myself to read the documentation. The exact instructions are found here https://github.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers for the positioning. Thanks again, @kboul.